# How do I count only non-empty columns in R, while included columns with sparse NA?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a matrix as such:

```
A      B      C     D
1      4      5     NA
43     3      NA    NA
85     NA     43    NA
4      2      NA    NA
```

I am trying to figure out how to count the number of non empty columns (In this case it would = 3). However if I do `ncol(df)` I get 4. How can I count only the columns that are not completely empty (idealy with base R or Tidyverse (trying not to use too many imported packages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may build a logical matrix with `is.na`, get the `colSums`, convert to a logical. vector (`> 0`) and get the `sum`

```
sum(colSums(!is.na(m1)) > 0)
[1] 3
```

---

Or may also use `Filter` on a `data.frame` and get the `ncol`

```
ncol(Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), as.data.frame(m1)))
[1] 3
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1L, 43L, 85L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, 5L, NA, 43L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", 
"B", "C", "D")))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This worked. I will accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows

Answer (score 1):

We could use `sum` and `sapply`

```
sum(sapply(df, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y))))>0))
```

output:

```
[1] 3
```